# Changed user password by providing new password as hash not syncing to filevault 2

Tags: macos, password, filevault, administrator

I have been using

defaults write "path/to/username.plist" shadowhashdata '(really long hash info)'

to administer a local support account on our Mac's but I have found, and it may be since updating to 10.10.1, that the file vault password is not getting updated when this is run.

Answer (score 2):

Updating an account's password for the FileVault 2 pre-boot login screen needs to involve the **opendirectoryd** process when changing the account's password. Writing the new password hash directly to the plist file bypasses **opendirectoryd**, so the password sync process never kicks in.

If you need to change the password this way, you may need to remove and re-add the user account with fdesetup. This will flush the old password's derived key for FileVault 2 and set up a derived key for the new password.

Remove:

```
fdesetup remove -user username_goes_here
```

Re-add:

```
fdesetup add -usertoadd username_goes_here
```

Note: As part of doing the remove and re-add, you will need to provide either the password of a FileVault 2-enabled account or a personal recovery key associated with the machine in order to authorize the changes. One thing that's important to keep in mind is that once you run **fdesetup remove** for your local administrator account, the account will no longer be enabled for FileVault 2 and will not be able to authorize the running of **fdesetup add**. Make sure you have a personal recovery key available or enable another user account for FileVault 2, then use the recovery key or that second account's password to authorize the re-adding of your local administrator account.

**Commentary**: I asked about the practice of writing password hashes to plist files in order to change passwords while I was at this year's WWDC. I received the following feedback from Apple engineers:

*"That's horrifying. Don't do that."*

[https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/8028](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/4276)